# Testing for differences in mean between two groups, how can I tell when samples come from paired observations or otherwise?

Tags: t-test, matching

In my class, we are covering tests of hypothesis about the mean. Two sample T-tests can be either paired or unpaired. When encountering problem descriptions, how can one determine from which study design was the sample ascertained?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  Please give some more context so that your question can be answered. As it stands it's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you:) In fact, I asked here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430202/when-i-read-the-question-related-to-two-population-hypothesis-test-how-can-i-de But I know that link is not legal in the website. Please give me an explanation. I need to learn quickly. Please:) thank you @Scortchi

Comment: does there exist enouh information for my queation? Will you help me? @Scortchi

Comment: It's just comparing matched pairs with independent samples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paired_t-test#Unpaired_and_paired_two-sample_t-tests

Comment: What does your question have to do with `time-series`? Are you just asking about `t-tests`?

Comment: Yes:) I guess.. There exist an effect of one thing like soap, pill, drug..etc, that is, if there "before/after" situation comparision, I will choose Matched paired. Otherwise, that's if there exist comparision of any two things, I Will choose indepent sample. Did I understand right? @scortchi

Comment: More or less: as the Wikipedia article explains, there's also the case where individuals are paired because they're similar in other respects than the variable being used in the t-test.

Comment: @Besct It's cross-posting that's frowned upon. Once you have done it, you might as well provide a link ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Paired T-tests generally come in one of a few flavors. Ultimately, you'll have to ask yourself whether each observation in the sample is independent. Correlation comes about when some shared, measurable conditions affect variability in a non-independent way in that sample. For instance, common household, twins, marriage, kidney transplant recipients and donors, time, etc. are all ways in which "correlated" measures can be drawn. If there are correlated pairs of observations (spouses, twins, etc.) , then the paired t-test is well motivated for inference. Sometimes the hypothesis determines this.

The most common scenario is that of a "pre/post" design where individuals are ascertained before and after some intervention is applied. If we believe that the intervention had some effect measurable as a difference in the arithmetic mean, then we can hypothesize that difference (in pre/post measures within an individual) to be zero and apply a 1 sample t-test to those sample *differences*.

Sometimes, it's not time but site that determines where repeated measures are drawn. Consider a test of lung function in which an MRI is taken at resting and during a deep inhale. You can compare left and right sites within a patient. We might hypothesize that there does not exist a dominant lung in individuals, so we set up a paired t-test to calculate the sample difference between the bigger lung and the smaller lung.

Comment: @Besct, if AdamO's answer resolved your confusion, you can thank him by *accepting* it. You do this by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer below the vote total.